# Cannot await my class

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am creating an ASP.NET Web Form. I created a `User` class which inherits from `IUser<string>`. In an other class, `ApplicationUserStore` which inherits from `IUserStore<User>`, I have two errors(the same error on both methods).

In the

```
public async Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName) 
    { return await database.Users.Where(x => x.Username == userName).First(); }
```

and

```
public async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId) 
    { return await database.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).First(); }
```

methdos I get the error: Cannot await User.

Why? What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Does .Where( .. ) return Task<IEnumerable<User>> ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`First()` is not an async-aware method.  It just executes the query synchronously.  What you want is `FirstAsync()`, an extension method defined in `System.Data.Entity`.  So add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

To your class, and modify your code to look like:

```
public async Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName) 
{ 
    return await database.Users.Where(x => x.Username == userName).FirstAsync(); 
}
```

This works, because `FirstAsync` returns a task that is awaitable.